# Thumping sound and pulsating brake pedal

Tags: brakes, vw, brake-rotor, noise

I'm driving a '12 VW Scirocco. Last Friday I had my winter tires put on at the shop, and I went for a 700 km road trip here in Norway. After some 100 kilometers I noticed my car making a cluncking/thumping sound as I applied brake pressure, and I also noticed pulsation in my brake pedal. The problem seems to have worsened over time. The pulsation and sound follows the rotation of the weel – ie. at high speeds the pulsation is more frequent than at low speeds.

I immediately suspected a warped rotor, but I am not sure how to resolve the problem. Do I have to take my car back to the shop and pay them a lot of money to get this fixed, or do you have any suggestions as to steps I can take myself to resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If it wasn't doing this before the tires, I'd suggest you check two things. First, ensure the lug nuts are correctly torqued (a loose wheel could cause you issues). Second, make sure all of your tires are still in good shape. One of them may have expired (seems less likely now that i"m thinking about it, but still I'd take a look). That the problem is getting worse is a bad thing, so you'll want to have it looked at sooner rather than later, for safety's sake.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2! I will check the lug nuts today, and if that doesn't resolve the problem I will have a mechanic take a look at the problem.